# How to assign a pointer to a list and print it out in c?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I've managed to point towards an array, however, the closest I've gotten to pointing to a char* list only prints out the individual letters as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
char* list[2];
list[0] = "Hullo";
list[1] = "GoodBye";
char* pointer = &(list);
char* back = *(list);
printf("%c", back[8]);
}
```

0 through 4 of back prints out "Hullo", 5 through 7 is whitespace, and 8 through 14 prints out "Goodbye".

I'm wondering how I can avoid printing this list character to character, as it becomes a very inconvenient issue when returning lists of unspecified sizes and planning on using them for another function etc.

Comment: Avoid accessing out-of-range. Strings in C are terminated by a null-character `'\0'`, so search for that.

Comment: To deal with a list with unspecified number of elements, pass the number of elements separately or insert a mark at the end of the list (for example, `NULL`).

Comment: The type of `&list` is *pointer to array of two pointers to `char`*. Or `char* (*)[2]`.

Comment: Also, `*list` is the same as `list[0]`, which means `back` is pointing to the first string, which is an array of 6 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char * list[2];
        list[0] = "Hullo";
        list[1] = "GoodBye";
        char ** pointer = list;
        for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof list / sizeof *list; i++ ){
                printf("%s\n", *pointer++);
        }
}
```

but maybe you're looking for something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **
foo(void)
{
        char **p = malloc(3 * sizeof *p);
        if( p == NULL ){
                perror("malloc");
                exit(1);
        }
        p[0] = "Hullo";
        p[1] = "GoodBye";
        p[2] = NULL;
        return p;
}

int
main(void)
{
        char **p = foo();
        for( ; *p; p++ ){
                printf("%s\n", *p);
        }
        free(p);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, when applying this to a function as:#include <stdio.h>

char** func()
{
    char* list[2];
    list[0] = "Hullo";
    list[1] = "GoodBye";
    char** pointer = list;
    return pointer;
}
main(void)
{
    char** pointer = func();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pointer / sizeof * pointer; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *pointer++);
    }
} It only returns the first-word "Hullo".

Comment: You cannot reference local variables after a function returns, and you cannot get the size of an array through a pointer to pointer.

Comment: Furthermore, when returning the function as my comment above, if I replace the code just after the function call in main() to     char * point = **pointer;
        printf("%c\n", point[8]);
It will print "G", bringing me back to my original question. What I want it to do is print "Hullo" with [0] and "Goodbye" with [1] to avoid any messy/hacky and inefficient code.

Comment: If `pointer` is of type `char **`, then `char *point = **pointer` is a type error.  It's still very unclear to me what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to return a char list from a function using a pointer. However, I've only been successful in printing each indiviual character, as you can see in my original question as well as my previous comment. I would like to print "Hullo" as list[0] and "Goodbye" as list[1].

Comment: I can't understand your original question at all!  In that, you are printing single characters with `%c` rather than strings.  You have a type error in the assignment of `pointer`, and you incur undefined behavior when you attempt to dereference `list[0][8]`.  Perhaps more importantly, see my first comment; you cannot reference a local variable after a function returns.  If you are building the array of strings in local variables, they are simply not available to you after the function returns.

Comment: @MadocSherbrook Added some more code that perhaps does what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Do I need to add a free() statement or does p free itself after the for loop? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you will need to free the value explicitly.